# Is --inspect-brk debugger feature still enabled in TestCafe

Tags: node.js, debugging, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Is the --inspect-brk debugger feature still enabled in TestCafe?

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/recipes/debug-tests/chrome-dev-tools.html

When I use it I get a wc URL but the TestCafe browser never launches.

I have an issue where our test website is not even launching in TestCafe proxy browser. I know this is an internal env issue, as the test website works manually in a regular browser. So I'm trying to get TestCafe logs to see what's blocking the test website from launching.

Versions:
node v10.15.3
testcafe v1.4.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's still enabled and works. I've checked it.
If the browser is not launched, probably there is some other issue. However, we haven't been reported about such issues. If you know the details on how to reproduce the issue, please create a separate ticket in the TestCafe github repository using the following form: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md

Comment: Thanks @Alex you are correct. I was missing the step to 'Resume' execution from inside the new Developer Tools. Once that was clicked TestCafe browser does indeed launch.